# Understanding そうとしか在れない

Tags: grammar

> 言葉とは裏腹にテレザの声は冷たい。雪の女王のような面差しが、今は真実凍りつくようだ。
>
> 貴方の前では**そうとしか在れない**とテレザは言って、そう在ってほしいと自分は望んだ。
>
> 許される幻影など、自分には永劫相応しくないから。
>
> 「代わりにはなり得ません。誰も彼も。人は常に、その人唯一の存在でございますれば」
>
> フレデリカが淡々と言う。
>
> 「それでも、人は清算を求めるものであろ。それがどのような形であれ」

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

What does the bold part mean and how should I understand the と in the bold part? Can the bold part be そうしか在れない, just like the following そう在って?

Comment: あれない is not too common.

Answer (score 2):

The following definition of [と](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8/#jn-154670) is relevant:

> ５ （副詞に付いて新たな副詞をつくり）ある状態を説明する意を表す。「そろそろ―歩く」「そよそよ―風が吹く」

I cannot explain why, but omitting と sounds odd. Also そうと在る does not sound idiomatic.

For comparison, そうしか考えられない is acceptable but less natural than そう**と**しか考えられない (= cannot think in other way than that) .

Comment: Thank you. So if omitting と is wrong, why can we say そう在ってほしい?

Comment: @chinoalpha I guess it is because it depends on the following predicate as a whole (在ってほしい). Also そう在りたい is fine. Another comparison: そう思う is more natural than そうと思う (barely acceptable).

Comment: @chinoalpha I cannot logically explain why we need と only when followed by しか... そうと思う and そうしか思えない both sound highly unnatural to me, too. Usually, しか can safely take adverbs; for exmample, ゆっくりしか走れない and ゆっくりとしか走れない are both natural.